# Exception rethrowing in java

Tags: java, exception

I've come across an exercise while preparing my OCA, i don't understand why the program print : `abce 3` instead of `abcde 3`. Here the program :

```
'public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("a");
         try{
            System.out.print("b");
             throw new IllegalArgumentException();
          }catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
              System.out.print("c");
              throw new RuntimeException("1");
          }catch(RuntimeException e) {
              System.out.print("d");
              throw new RuntimeException("2");
          }finally {
            System.out.print("e");
            throw new RuntimeException("3");
          }
        }'
```

Any explanations why it ignores the last catch block  will be really appreciated!

Comment: `Another problem is that the exception thrown in the last catch block is simply ignored or masked by the one thrown in the finally block`. Yes, that is a problem, but it's a problem built into Java :) Don't throw exceptions from finally blocks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `finally` block is **always** executed after a `try-catch` block, therefore `e` is printed. `abc` are obvious, as you throw an exception in `try` and the corresponding `catch` block for `IllegalArgumentException` is entered.

However, since you throw a new exception `RuntimeException` **inside the catch block**, it is thrown to the caller of your method. The `catch` blocks **only** handles exceptions thrown in a `try` block, all others are passed on to the caller of the function you throw the exception in.